# Video Conversion Automated Application

Tags: java, video, automation, type-conversion

I am trying to create an application where you are able to convert video's to different formats where the video is saved on a web server so that the user can access it once the conversion is complete. What would you recommend as the best way of approaching this?

Example:
-Download a video from a particular website.
-Be able to convert it to MP4 and save the file on a web server.
-Send a notification to the user with the link of the MP4 video.
-Access and download the MP4 video from the link.

So basically the user downloads a video (in ARF format). My program should take that ARF video and convert it to MP4. Once converted, the mp4 saved on a web server and the user informed (i.e. by email) that the conversion has been completed. The user should then be able to view the link and download the MP4 video. I also want to make sure that the program works on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Users can manually specify the file to be converted. I am most confident with Java so is there a way this can be achieved using some of Java's API Libraries & Web Applications?

I was thinking of using JAVE libraries to do the conversion but am not too sure how to then save the video on a web server.

Comment: Your question is probably to broad to give a single answer to. There are a wide range of libraries for working with and converting between media formats. You are also not specifying if you expect the server to do the actual fetching, or if users should manually upload the files.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the post to make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

There are several Java libraries for working with various media formats. A prominent one is JFFMPG:

http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/

There is also JAVE, which you may find easier to user, depending on your needs:

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php

Comment: It seems as though that the JAVE Library doesnt support ARF Video formats